# Make nested div full screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, innerhtml

Any idea how to stretch the thumbnail div to be full screen? I've tried a couple of methods and the closest I got to my desired output was by setting the innerHTML of the parent div with class container with the contents of the hidden div, but I still have to revert it and add some animations to not have the change so abrupt. Basically I want the Thumbnail div to rotate on Y axis and on its back some info can be found. Upon completion of the Y rotation I want it to go full screen(like a popup) and have a X button to close and get everything back to normal.

Below is the HTML, CSS and JS(didn't add the entire HTML, it would've been redundant)

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="info-review">
        <p>Latest Version: 6.2.4<br/>
        Catia<br/>
        Last : 02.07.2013</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row flex">

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">                 
                <img src="assets/img/Contact.jpg">  
                <p>1<sup>st</sup> level support<div class="boxed-plus" aria-hidden="true"></div></p>        
            </div>                      
        </div>      

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">                 
                <img src="assets/img/support.jpg">  
                <p>1<sup>st</sup> level support<div class="boxed-plus" aria-hidden="true"></div></p>            
            </div>                      
        </div>  

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">                 
                <img src="assets/img/license.jpg">
                    <p>1<sup>st</sup> level support<div class="boxed-plus" aria-hidden="true"></div></p>    
            </div>                      
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">                 
                <img src="assets/img/application.jpg">  
                <p>1<sup>st</sup> level support<div class="boxed-plus" aria-hidden="true"></div></p>            
            </div>                      
        </div>

    </div> <!-- row -->

</div> <!-- container -->

<div id="info1"><p>         BASE: ENGAGE IN THE HOME CARE-RELATED ACTIVITY  (H_HOMEACTIVITIES=6)16_6. What do you do first in order to...? Select one.Look for inspiration (e.g., for closet organization)ONLY SHOW IF SELECTED AT Q15_6. SHOW IN SAME ORDER.IF ONLY ONE ANSWER SELECTED FOR ITEM/QUESTION AT Q15_6, AUTOCODE THAT OPTION AT HERE AND DO NOT SHOW THIS QUESTION.<div class="boxed-plus" aria-hidden="true"></div>   </p>    </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 115px;
    background: #143872;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1d355b, #4a83e0, #143872);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(#1d355b, #4a83e0, #143872); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.container {
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: inherit;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;  
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top: none;
    background: #143872;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1d355b, #4a83e0, #143872);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(#1d355b, #4a83e0, #143872); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

@media(max-width: 600px){
    .navbar{
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0; 
    }
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 14px 16px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-header table{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color: #10203a;
}

.navbar-right{
    float: right;
}

.navbar a img{
    float:left;
}

.dropmenu{
    transition: all .5s ease;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

@media(max-width: 547px){
    .navbar a{
        padding: 0;
    }
    .navbar-right{
        float: none;
    }
    .dropmenu{
        margin: 0;
    }
}

.dropmenu:hover {
    height: 100px;
}

.dropmenu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
}

.dropmenu table{
    height: 50px;
}

.lang{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.dropmenu li{
    display: block;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    height: 50px;
}

.info-review{
    padding: 0 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: white;
    border: 1px dashed white;
    border-top-left-radius: 85px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 85px;
}

@media(min-width: 500px){
    .container .info-review{
        width: 40%;
    }
}

.info-review p{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

@media(max-width: 900px){
    .info-review p{
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;  
  border-top: 5px solid white;
}

.selection-arrow {
    padding-top: 17px;
}

.thumbnail {
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
            transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(500);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
}

.thumbnail > img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.thumbnail p{
    color:white;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
}

.thumbnail > div{
    max-width: 100%;
}

.row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}

.flex { 
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
} 

.col-md-4, .col-lg-3, .col-sm-6{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

@media(min-width: 600px){
    .col-sm-6{
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 900px){
    .col-md-4{
        width: 33.33333333%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .col-lg-3{
        width: 25%;
    }
}

.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 25px;
  width:auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

.active {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(-3em) translateZ(3em);
}

.active > p {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    color: red;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    float: right;
}

img {
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
}
figure:hover img {
    box-shadow: none;
}
figcaption {
    background-color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
    border: 1px dashed white;

    z-index: 99 !important;
}
figure:hover figcaption {
    visibility: visible;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 15px -10px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25);
    margin: 100px auto;
}

.boxed-plus {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 20%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #143872;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1d355b, #4a83e0, #143872);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(#1d355b, #4a83e0, #143872); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */  
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.boxed-plus::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: -2.5px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 9;
}
.boxed-plus::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 5px;
  margin-left: -2.5px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.activity {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
}

#info1{
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}
```

JS:

```
var plus_clicked = document.querySelectorAll('.boxed-plus');
var info_1 = document.getElementById('info1');
var clicked = false;

plus_clicked.forEach(function(e){
    e.addEventListener('click',function(){
        if(clicked === false){
            var previous_html = e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
            clicked === true;
            e.classList.add('activity');
            this.parentNode.classList.add('active');

            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(e.parentNode.innerHTML);
                //e.parentNode.innerHTML = info_1.innerHTML;
                e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML = info_1.innerHTML;
            }, 300);

            console.log(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
    }else{
        e.innerHTML = previous_html;
    }
    });
})
```

Comment: Which `div` do you want full screen? And by full-screen, do you mean hiding the browser's address bar and the OS chrome. Or, do you just mean full-page?

Comment: inside all the div's with class="thumbnail" there is a div that it's styled to look like a plus. Upon clicking this plus I want the parent div to rotate and then go full-screen. By full-screen I mean the browser window(full-page). I don't want the address bar to hide or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR ;)

You can just set the `width` and `height` of the element to `100vw` and `100vh` respectively.

Demo:

```js
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color:aliceblue;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
}

div.active {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div>Click to Expand</div>
```

Comment: this solves some issues, thanks. But I still need to move the entire thing in the topmost left corner such that the expanded div covers the entire page and I don't get any lateral scrolling

Comment: @Shobolan No problem. Just use absolute positioning. I'll update the answer.

Comment: this is where the problem stands in. By using absolute positioning the thumbnail div is no longer constraint inside the parent( which is <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6"> ) but when setting top and left to 0 it goes to the top and left parts of the div witch class = "container", instead of top and left parts of the body.

Comment: It would only go to the top-left of the parent if the parent was, itself absolutely positioned. If not, it will be positioned at the top-left of body.

Comment: Yay, found the problem. I had the parent with position set to relative. Thanks man.